# Next.js - React.js - express: Why getInitialProps() - is called everytime when using 'shallow - routing'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js, server-side-rendering

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-shallow-routing

I'm trying to create filter feature to my site and want to push parameters to url that i can share 'filtered' -url

`import Router from 'next/router'`

```
.
.
changeurl = () => {
  console.log('----add params to url----')
  const path = Router.asPath
  const newPath = `${path}/?param=hi`
  // Router.replace(newPath , newPath, { shallow: true })
  Router.push(newPath, newPath, {
    shallow: true
  })
}
.
.
```

if i understand right, `getInitialProps()` - functions should not been called again when `Router.push()`/ `Router.replace()`  `shallow` - option is set to *true* ?

Comment: Correct. This should work. Though, where is the problem?

Comment: I use nextJs dynamic routes ( `import { Router } from 'routes' ` ) so API looks like this - `Router.pushRoute(route, params, options)` --> `Router.pushRoute(newPath, {
      shallow: true
    })`